# Ansible yum: Loop over Mirrors, Stop on Succes

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I was recently trying to install the rpmfusion-free repo with ansible on a remote Host running rhel. All of a sudden, the servers weren't reachable anymore.

The PC running ansible runs on Ubuntu 16.10 with:

```
$> ansible --version                                                                                                            
   ansible 2.2.1.0
   config file =
   configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

I decided to tackle the problem by using ansible to iterate over a List of mirrors of the rpmfusion repo, and using the first one, that works, aka looping over the list of mirrors, and stopping on success.

Here is the code as it was before:

```
- name: Install RPM-Fusion free
  yum:
    name: http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/updates/6/i386/rpmfusion-free-release-6-1.noarch.rpm
    state: present
    disable_gpg_check: true
  become: true
```

And here is what i've tried:

```
- name: Install RPM-Fusion free
  yum:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
    disable_gpg_check: true
  become: true
  register: result
  until: result | succeeded
  retries: 4
  with_items: "{{ rpmfusion_free_mirrors }}"


rpmfusion_free_mirrors:
  - "http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/updates/6/i386/rpmfusion-free-release-6-1.noarch.rpm"
  - "http://mirrors.netix.net/rpmfusion/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-6.noarch.rpm"
  - "http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-6.noarch.rpm"
  - "http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net/rpmfusion/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-6.noarch.rpm"
```

As you may have guessed, this fails with the output:

> FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: install-backend-rpms : Install RPM-Fusion free (4 retries left).
>   FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: install-backend-rpms : Install RPM-Fusion free (3 retries left).
>   FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: install-backend-rpms : Install RPM-Fusion free (2 retries left).
>   FAILED - RETRYING: TASK: install-backend-rpms : Install RPM-Fusion free (1 retries left).
>   failed: [backend_ans_test] (item=[u'http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/updates/6/i386/rpmfusion-free-release-6-1.noarch.rpm', u'http://mirrors.netix.net/rpmfusion/free/
>   el/rpmfusion-free-release-6.noarch.rpm', u'http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-6.noarch.rpm', u'http://mirror.de.leasew
>   eb.net/rpmfusion/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-6.noarch.rpm']) => {"attempts": 4, "failed": true, "item": ["http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/updates/6/i386/rpmfusion
>   -free-release-6-1.noarch.rpm", "http://mirrors.netix.net/rpmfusion/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-6.noarch.rpm", "http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/rpmfusion.org/
>   free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-6.noarch.rpm", "http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net/rpmfusion/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-6.noarch.rpm"], "msg": "Failure downloading http://dow
>   nload1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/updates/6/i386/rpmfusion-free-release-6-1.noarch.rpm, 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'"}

It seems to me, as if ansible considers the task failed, when one of the mirrors is not reachable. I, however, want ansible to go through the mirrors and stop looping until the one of them succeeds.

I've stumbled across a google-groups thread from 2014 ([GoogleGroups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/ansible-project/uJqSmkKTpZc/bfDA3MM0dmIJ)) stating, that this simply doesnt work. Does any of you know, if there now is a feature like this or if i can achieve some similar functionality in a different manner?

Best wishes and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ansible will evaluate the status on each loop iteration, you should add:

```
failed_when: false
```

or

```
ignore_errors: true
```

But then Ansible will always proceed to the next task, so if you want to break the flow in case all mirrors failed, you should add another one to check the `result`.

Answer (score 1):

Two years late, but I struggled with something similar, so I'm leaving my answer here for future reference.

I believe you were looking for somehting like this:

```
- name: Install RPM-Fusion free
  yum:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
    disable_gpg_check: true
  become: true
  register: result
  when: result is undefined or result.failed
  with_items: "{{ rpmfusion_free_mirrors }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get Ocab19's solution to work without a deprecation warning:

[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Invoking "yum" only once while using a loop via squash_actions is deprecated. Instead of using
 a loop to supply multiple items and specifying `name: "{{ item }}"`, please use `name: 
...` and remove the loop. 
This feature will be removed in version 2.11. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting 
deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.

However I don't see how the same behavior can be accomplished post deprecation.

So instead I attempt to download from each of the sources, then install after successful download:

```
# download the source if it's not in the images mount
 - name: grab RPM-fusion repo image
   get_url:
     url: "https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-7.noarch.rpm"
     dest: /misc/images/rpmfusion-free-release-7.noarch.rpm
     force: no
   ignore_errors: true

 - name: grab RPM-fusion repo image from alternate source
   get_url:
     url: "http://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/rpmfusion/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-7.noarch.rpm"
     dest: /misc/images/rpmfusion-free-release-7.noarch.rpm
     force: no
   ignore_errors: true

 - name: Install RPM-Fusion free for vlc
   yum: 
     name: /misc/images/rpmfusion-free-release-7.noarch.rpm
     state: present
```